# Zoomable timeline with one element per tick (D3V6)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a timeline-based chart that should always have one rect per x-axis tick. The idea is to use the color of each rectangle to convey the amount of data that's in that date (somewhat like a [heatmap](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/heatmap)).

The chart also has grouped y values. That is, there are two y axes: one for each group, and inside each of those, three lines (subgroups). Semantically the intention is to say: "*For this coupon, on this date, there are this many readings for each data type*". To help clear up my intention further, [this library](http://vasturiano.github.io/timelines-chart/example/categorical/) has a very similar solution to what I'm aiming at.

**OK, and your question...?**

My question is about aligning the rectangles with the ticks, and keeping them that way. How can I make them always be aligned with the ticks? Is there a way to "tie" a rect to a tick?
To make matters worst, the chart has to be zoomable, so when you scroll and the dimensions of the ticks change, the rectangles should stick to their corresponding ticks: move with them, change their width accordingly and so on. Basically, I'd like to "marry" the rects to their corresponding ticks.

**What have you tried?**

My approach right now is to make the segments' width depend on the current tick count, and essentially treat the current ticks as if they were my data.
That is:

```
segmentWidth = state.width() / ticks.length;
```

And when updating/rendering the rects:

```
state.mainG.selectAll('g.couponData')
    .selectAll('g.column')
    .data(ticks)
    ...
```

One problem I see with this is that if you click and drag, the ticks expand, so having a single, global `segmentWidth` doesn't seem like the right approach. Seems like I'd need a way to grab each tick and get the distance to the next one, and use that as the width of each corresponding segment, but I haven't quite got there yet.

**Here's a fiddle with an example of what I have:**
https://jsfiddle.net/bnekvp0o/11/

TBH, I presume I'm making some dumb calculation mistakes, but I also feel like I'm bruteforcing the solution, so I'm hesitant to keep trying to make it work with my current approach, since I'm quite new to the framework.

Thanks in advance!